# winform showdialog not returning a value

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]Main form on click function and return value function

```
 private void xButton9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form Child_frm = new Select_doctor();
            Child_frm.ShowDialog(this);
          //  if()
            {
                using (var form = new Select_doctor())
                {
                    string val = form.ReturnValue1;            //values preserved after close
                    string dateString = form.ReturnValue2;
                    MessageBox.Show(form.ReturnValue1);
                }
            }

        }
```

Child form on click of grid form

```
public partial class Select_doctor : Form
    {
        public Select_doctor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int Userid=Helper.ReadFromJsonUser_id("login.json");
            MessageBox.Show(Userid.ToString());


        }

        private void Grid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            Object row = this.Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Sl"].Value;

            Visual_aid_new.GetDoctorNmae(Convert.ToInt32(row.ToString()));
            this.Cus = 100;
            this.ReturnValue1 = "Something";
            this.ReturnValue2 = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            using (var form = new Visual_aid_new(0, 0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(row.ToString())))
            {

                form.Number = 10;

                MessageBox.Show(ReturnValue1);
                MessageBox.Show(ReturnValue2);
            }
            this.Close();
          //  var myForm = new Visual_aid_new(0,0,0,Convert.ToInt32(row.ToString()));

        }




        public  string ReturnValue1 { get; set; }
        public  string ReturnValue2 { get; set; }

        private int number = 0;
        public int Cus
        { get { return number; } set { number = value; } }
    }
```

The problem is string is not returning main function;Can anyone help me to resolve.Hey attached all codes please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access properties of your custom class based on `Form`, you need to define `Child_frm` as a `Select_doctor` not its base class `Form`. You also need to read the returned values from the instance of `Select_doctor` that you called `Show_Dialog()` on. You were looking for the values in a brand new instance of `Select_doctor`.

```
 private void xButton9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Select_doctor Child_frm = new Select_doctor();
        Child_frm.ShowDialog(this);
      //  if() check for valid form here
        {
            string val = Child_frm.ReturnValue1;            //values preserved after close
            string dateString = Child_frm.ReturnValue2;
            MessageBox.Show(Child_frm.ReturnValue1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: its not allow me to call directly from child form  string val = Child_frm.ReturnValue1;         string dateString = Child_frm.ReturnValue2; its giving error

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't allow you to directly call from your variable? What's  the error says? @weirdev is giving you the correct answer.

Comment: @RashmiS Can you edit your post to show how you are defining `ReturnValue1` and `ReturnValue2` within Select_doctor?

Comment: In child form value is returning correctly.giving does't contain ReturnValue1 and ReturnValue2

Comment: @RashmiS Can you post the error code as well? I'm not seeing any problem here.